# sed delete all lines between two lines that contain a string

Tags: sed

I have a text file with thousand of lines. I want to delete all lines between the line that  starts with XXX and the line that starts with YYY, example

```
1
2
3
XXX
a
b
c
YYY
x
z
y
```

should be:

```
1
2
3
x
z
y
```

Is that possible with sed or similar?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^XXX/{:a;N;/^YYY/Md;ba}' file
```

This will delete lines between a line beginning `XXX` and a line beginning `YYY`. As will:

```
sed '/^XXX/,/^YYY/d' file
```

However if the beginning `YYY`is not matched, the first solution will not remove any lines at all, whereas the second solution will remove all lines from the initial match of `XXX` to the end of the file.

A slightly different solution for removing lines between lines containing `XXX` and `YYY` is:

```
sed '/XXX/{:a;N;/\n.*YYY/d;ba}' file
```

The second regexp ensures that `YYY` does not appear on the first line of the match.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
sed '/XXX/,/YYY/d'
```